# Django - Check users messages every request

Tags: django

I want to check if a user has any new messages each time they load the page. Up until now, I have been doing this inside of my views but it's getting fairly hard to maintain since I have a fair number of views now.

I assume this is the kind of thing middleware is good for, a check that will happen every single page load. What I need it to do is so:

1. Check if the user is logged in
2. If they are, check if they have any messages
3. Store the result so I can reference the information in my templates

Has anyone ever had to write any middleware like this? I've never used middleware before so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use middleware for this purpose, but perhaps [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) are more inline for what you want to do.

With middleware, you are attaching data to the request object. You could query the database and find a way to jam the messages into the request. But context processors allow you to make available extra entries into the context dictionary for use in your templates.

I think of middleware as providing extra information to your views, while context processors provide extra information to your templates. This is in no way a rule, but in the beginning it can help to think this way (I believe).

```
def messages_processor(request):
    return { 'new_messages': Message.objects.filter(unread=True, user=request.user) }
```

Include that processor in your settings.py under context processors. Then simply reference `new_messages` in your templates.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't looked at context processors but it seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this middleware on my site for rendering messages. It checks a cookie, if it is not present it appends the message to request and saves a cookie, maybe you can do something similar:

```
class MyMiddleware:


 def __init__(self):
        #print 'Initialized my Middleware'
        pass

    def process_request(self, request):        
        user_id = False
        if request.user.is_active:                
            user_id = str(request.user.id)                            
        self.process_update_messages(request, user_id)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        self.process_update_messages_response(request, response)
        return response

    def process_update_messages(self, request, user_id=False):
        update_messages = UpdateMessage.objects.exclude(expired=True)         
        render_message = False 
        request.session['update_messages'] = []
        for message in update_messages:                        
            if message.expire_time < datetime.datetime.now():
                message.expired = True
                message.save()
            else:                
                if request.COOKIES.get(message.cookie(), True) == True:
                    render_message = True
                if render_message:
                    request.session['update_messages'].append({'cookie': message.cookie(), 'cookie_max_age': message.cookie_max_age})
                    messages.add_message(request, message.level, message)
                    break

    def process_update_messages_response(self, request, response):
        try:
            update_messages = request.session['update_messages']
        except:
            update_messages = False
        if update_messages:            
            for message in update_messages:
                response.set_cookie(message['cookie'], value=False, max_age=message['cookie_max_age'], expires=None, path='/', domain=None, secure=None)
        return response
```